# Does BitTorrent verify files' integrity?

Tags: checksum, bittorrent

When I download, say an ISO image, using a torrent; should I still verify the file's integrity (by calculating sha256 hash, for example), or is this done automatically while downloading?

Comment: Just to clarify, when I said _BitTorrent_ in the title, what I meant was the [_BitTorrent_ _Protocol_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent), i.e., the protocol used by clients to download torrents; and not the [_BitTorrent_ _client_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28software%29).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The BitTorrent protocol has a mechanism for automatically verifying each chunk's integrity after download.  Of course, this should only reassure you if you trust the source of the file.

If you have a checksum for the whole file (eg. for some software package), you can definitely verify the file yourself afterwards.

> Torrent files have an "announce" section, which specifies the URL of the tracker, and an "info" section, containing (suggested) names for the files, their lengths, the piece length used, and a SHA-1 hash code for each piece, all of which are used by clients to verify the integrity of the data they receive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bittorrent